# Extremely Slow Google Cloud Function (1 minute +)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function to handle username and profile picture changes in my firestore database. Whenever a user updates their profile picture or name, a cloud function updates all their reviews so they match the new data. However, this function is taking over a minute to run, even though I only have a single review in the database.

Why is this happening and is there a more efficient way to perform this update?

```
exports.onProfilePictureOrNameChange = functions.firestore
.document("userProfiles/{userProfileId}")
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const userNamebefore = change.before.data().usePreferredName ? change.before.data().preferredName : change.before.data().fullName;
    const userNameAfter = change.after.data().usePreferredName ? change.after.data().preferredName : change.after.data().fullName;
    const nameChanged = userNamebefore !== userNameAfter;
    const profilePictureChanged = change.after.data().profilePictureURL !== change.before.data().profilePictureURL;

    if (nameChanged || profilePictureChanged) {
        const data = {
            profilePictureURL: change.after.data().profilePictureURL,
            userName: userNameAfter,
        };

        afs.collection("reviews").where("userProfileId", "==", change.after.id).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                doc.ref.update(data);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you try using `Promise.all()` instead of updating each document in a forEach loop as in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/dc64a9d2d7c86f7cb2f485041317ab27) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the top-level code in your Cloud Functions, which means that the container has no way to know when the code is done.

To make it work correctly, return a promise from the top-level code that resolves when all asynchronous work is done. And as Dharmaraj commented, you'll need to use `Promise.all` to signal the completion of the nested writes in the loop.

So something like:

```
exports.onProfilePictureOrNameChange = functions.firestore
.document("userProfiles/{userProfileId}")
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const userNamebefore = change.before.data().usePreferredName ? change.before.data().preferredName : change.before.data().fullName;
    const userNameAfter = change.after.data().usePreferredName ? change.after.data().preferredName : change.after.data().fullName;
    const nameChanged = userNamebefore !== userNameAfter;
    const profilePictureChanged = change.after.data().profilePictureURL !== change.before.data().profilePictureURL;

    if (nameChanged || profilePictureChanged) {
        const data = {
            profilePictureURL: change.after.data().profilePictureURL,
            userName: userNameAfter,
        };

        return afs.collection("reviews").where("userProfileId", "==", change.after.id).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            const promises = querySnapshot.docs.nap((doc) => {
                return doc.ref.update(data);
            });
            return Promise.all(promises);
        });
    }
});
```

I strongly recommend checking out the documentation on [sync, async and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and the video series linked in there, as it pays to understand how asynchronous behavior affects execution of your Cloud Functions.